# Sublime. Как определить причину сообщения "shell_cmd or cmd is required"

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

При работе с css файлами Sublime выдет сообщение

shell_cmd or cmd is required 
    [cmd: None] 
    [dir: C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\sass] 
    [path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo Edit 9\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm; C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32; C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts]
    [Finished]

**Как определить причину сообщения? 

Как исправить эту ошибку или хотя бы отключить появление?**
(все работает корректно, никаких помех в работе не выявлено)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот что накопал](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265949/miktex-failing-to-compile-in-sublime-text-3). Возможно у вас в настройках build system что-то не так.

Comment: Увы. Этот плагин даже не установливался.

Comment: О точно! Дело именно в build system.

Comment: **1)** Совсем не «очевидно». // **2)** Предлагать откатывать до ST2, когда уже несколько лет используется ST3 на мой взгляд вредно. // **3)** Прежде чем отключать плагин, полезно попытаться его починить. // Исходя из данных аргументов, полагаю, что лучше убрать первый абзац ответа. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, и Shell Turtlestein у меня хорошо работает на Sublime Text 3 Build 3126. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Ну да, вы правы. Я пользовался этим редактором очень давно, сейчас им не пользуюсь. Тогда 3 версия была сырой, по этому машинально предложил такой вариант (хотя она вроде как до сих пор бета). По поводу "очевидно" - я вкладывал в это слово значение "вероятно", никак не "безусловно".

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.